# jqplot reversing y axis points and other problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am getting this kind of result:
[image]

Which is weird because why on earth am I getting this values on my y axis `1 1 2 2 2`. My expected Y Axis points are just 1 and 2 since the result that I have is

`[[["2013-01-30", "2"], ["2013-01-31", "2"], ["2013-02-01", "1"]]]`

What i'm trying to do here is to reverse the Y axis as being 1 as the highest or on the top, just like on the screenshot.

Here is my code:

I am getting this one on my json result via ajax. This is the result:

`[{"execution_datetime":"2013-01-30","sales_rank":"2"},{"execution_datetime":"2013-01-31","sales_rank":"2"},{"execution_datetime":"2013-02-01","sales_rank":"1"}]` , that is the result of the data on the `jQuery.each`

```
  var response =[[]];
    var maxSR = 1;
    jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
        if( this.sales_rank > maxSR ) {
        maxSR = this.sales_rank; //I am getting the largest number in the response array so that I can assign it on the Y-AXIS MIN 
        }
        response[0].push([this.execution_datetime, this.sales_rank]);
    });

    //response has already a value of:
    //[[["2013-01-30", "2"], ["2013-01-31", "2"], ["2013-02-01", "1"]]]

    var tmpMin = response[0][0];
    var xMin = tmpMin[0];

    var plot2 = $.jqplot('myChart',response,{
    axes:{
        xaxis:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions:{formatString:'%b %#d'},
            tickInterval:"1 days",
            min: xMin,
          },
        yaxis:{
            tickOptions:{ formatString:'%d'  },
            max:1,
            min:parseInt(maxSR),
        },
    },
        highlighter:{
            show:true,
            sizeAdjust: 7.5,
        },
        cursor: {
          show:false,
        },
  });
```

I also tried removing the `tickOptions:{ formatString:'%d'  },` on the y-axis, it seems to be working, the problem is that, I am getting some floats on my Y-Axis which I don't like. How would I solve that one?

Another question incase this will be solved, is it possible to set a kind of offset to the x axis so that the points won't lie on the border?

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you! :)

Comment: First problem: `sales_rank` is a string, it needs to be a number

Comment: Nothing happened when I changed the string into number

Answer (score 1):

With this you can reverse the Y axis values:

```
tickOptions:{ formatString:'%i'}
```

To eliminate values on your y axis 1 1 2 2 2 you should use:

```
numberTicks: value
```

> is it possible to set a kind of offset to the x axis so that the points won't lie on the border?

You could use this:

```
xaxis:{
//
min: xMin <-- subtract 1 to this value.

//
yaxis:{
   min: parseInt(maxSR) <-- subtract 1 to this value.
```

Comment: Actually the tickOptions that you provided did not work, the only thing that worked is the numberTicks:value

Answer (score 0):

I think the max is 1 and min is 2 in the below code. You want to set max to 2 and min to 1

```
yaxis:{
                tickOptions:{ formatString:'%d'  },
                max:1,
                min:parseInt(maxSR),
            },
```

Example

```
 yaxis:{
                    tickOptions:{ formatString:'%d'  },
                    max:2,
                    min:1,
                },
```